# How to add an href link to a text in Android?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm scraping some web data using `jsoup` and I can fetch the link and text differently. I want to create hyperlinks for those text using the links I've fetched. I'm new to Android Development so I don't know how to implement it or what to look for exactly.

Below is the sample code that I've tried:

```
private void getWebsite(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try{                  
            Document doc = 
            Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

            builder.append(title).append("\n");

            for(Element link : links){
                builder.append("\n").append("Link: 
                ").append(link.attr("href"))
                        .append("\n").append("Text: 
                         ").append(link.text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
         builder.append("Error").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(builder.toString());
            }
        });
    }
     }).start();
}
```

I want the texts clickable and it should redirect to links from the app.

Comment: @PaoloMossini my problem is different regarding that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To linkify text link url in `TextView` use [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) instead of regular `StringBuilder` and set [URLSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan) for each clickable content:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
...
for (Element link : links) {
    final String url = link.attr("href");
    builder.
            ....
            .append("Link: ")
            .append(url, new URLSpan(url), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            .append("\n")
            ...
}
```

and finaly

```
textView.setText(builder);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```